# where will gethostbyaddr() get the hostname from

Tags: resolution, gethostbyaddr

In case of gethostbyname(), it returns ip addr by doing name resolution using DNS and /etc/hosts or Netbios.

How will gethostbyaddr() work? how will this function get hostname from address ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how host resolution is configured in the box.
It could get from /etc/hostnames or so
or from DNS or so...